# A word meaning to remember emotionally or sadly?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What is the word used for remembering something when the memory makes one emotional or sad? Like thinking of a beloved who is not there anymore or something that happened in the past.

I looked and found the word *reminisce,* but it's used for joyful recollection of past events. But I want the word for sadness or emotional thoughts associated with the past. Please include an example sentence.

Comment: Getting nostalgic. This can conjure a wide range of very specific emotions (and could be called an emotion in itself, perhaps) but basically refers to remembering something and getting emotional about it.

Comment: Portuguese _saudade_ is pretty good for this, but it's not really an English word.

Answer (score 3):

[Wistful](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wistful?s=t).

From Dictionary.com:

> 1. characterized by melancholy; longing; yearning.
> 2. pensive, especially in a melancholy way.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a specific word for remember sadly in general. Thinking of a death or other traumatic event in the past is *mourning* or *lamenting*. If remembering a missed opportunity or a mistake made in the past then you are *regretting* it.

Other than those specific cases then I would say remember sadly or recall sadly.

References: Google dictionary service

Answer (score 0):

Nostalgize

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/nostalgize

Also appears occasionally as *nostalogize.*

*Nostalogize* appears in quotes in *Life,* as referenced here: https://www.google.com/search?q=nostalogize

As a US American, this is a term I've heard repeatedly. I'm surprised to find so few references to it online.

It is a verb form of the more commonly encountered noun, *nostalgia,* which is usually described as a bittersweet emotional experience.

[: pleasure and sadness that is caused by remembering something from the past and wishing that you could experience it again](http://i.word.com/idictionary/nostalgia)

Here is an example sentence: *As I watched the old man taking his last breaths, I began* nostalgizing *about my childhood, remembering how he had taught me to ride a bike, to work hard, and to take care of those you love.*

*Nostalgizing* appears, also marked in quotes, in *The New York Times* in a 2013 article: 
http://mobile.nytimes.com/2013/07/09/science/what-is-nostalgia-good-for-quite-a-bit-research-shows.html?pagewanted=all&referrer=&_r=0

Comment: Thanks for answer. Also reminisce is used only for en joyful recollection of past events. Am I right?

Comment: Well, some dictionaries include the idea of enjoyability under *reminisce,* but not all. At least often, it means an enjoyable remembering. It can be used neutrally of emotion: to recall something about the past. But it does not normally carry the sweet/sad emotional meaning that nostalgizing/nostalogizing does.

Answer (score -2):

Elegiac...  thinking of the past that can't be repeated.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but citing a source would make it a better answer.