# Is there a single word for emotional baggage?

Tags: single-word-requests

ie. Barry couldn’t go to such and such bar anymore because it reminded him of where he met his first love that didn’t work out and he had to much emotional baggage

Comment: A few verbs spring to mind rather than nouns. But I would rewrite from scratch. It's a clumsily written sentence and fixing just one word in it won't make it less clumsy. (Nota bene: "i.e." is not the same thing as "e.g.". Just like "to" is not the same thing as "too".)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258856/a-word-meaning-to-remember-emotionally-or-sadly

Comment: “Bullshit” comes to mind. If you are trying to write in English, focus on the ideas you wish to express and try to state them simply and clearly. You should be working with formulations such as “…because it invoked bitter memories of his shattered first romance”. And you mean eg, not i.e., and sentences end with a full stop / period.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_baggage) says about *emotional baggage*:

> **Emotional baggage** is an everyday expression that correlates with many varied but similar concepts within social sciences, self-help movements, and other fields: its general concern is with unresolved issues of an emotional nature, often with an implication that the emotional baggage is detrimental.
>
> As a metaphorical image, it is that of carrying all the disappointments, wrongs, and trauma of the past around with one in a heavy load.

Different context *can* have it mean different things. However, given the above, I think the single work most likely to represent it in a lot of cases would be [**trauma**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trauma):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : an injury (such as a wound) to living tissue caused by an extrinsic agent
> **1 b** : a disordered psychic or behavioral state resulting from severe mental or emotional stress or physical injury
> **1 c** : an emotional upset
> // the personal *trauma* of an executive who is not living up to his own expectations
> — Karen W. Arenson

*Baggage* is something you have to carry around as an unwanted chore; it's not something that you look forward to dealing with.

Figuratively speaking, it would be uncommon for somebody to use the term *emotional baggage* to refer to something positive or happy. If they *aren't* talking about something emotionally scarring (*traumatic*), then they would normally either not use the term at all or they would qualify it in some way.

To paraphrase the example sentence slightly:

> It reminded him of where he met his first love that didn’t work out, and he had too much *trauma* from that experience.

Comment: “Emotional baggage is an everyday expression”.  The *contributer* to Wikipedia wrote that has a nice sense of humour.